# In react js, how to get correct state between click and mouseleave in short time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a button, I clicked the button and change some state, and leave the button immediately after clicking the button, you will found the state is doesn't change.

i want the newest state, when mouseLeave event is called

```
const App = (props) => {
  var [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => setVisible(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => console.log(visible)}
    >
      test
    </button>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

how are you determining onMouseLeave is not triggered? Have you tried adding console.log statements? I'm wondering if instead you are experiencing a bad ordering for onMouseOver/onMouseOut because the setting of states is not a synchronous action. I created a simple react component and I couldn't easily reproduce. –
noveyak

It happen sometimes, that when leaving element onMouseLeave function is not called.. Yes i tried with logging and function is not being called.. then how should i implement hover event? –
zazmaister

You could try onMouseOver/onMouseOut to see if it works better for you since I think these events are better supported although the behavior of this is slightly different so might not be suitable for your application. –
noveyak

Answer (score 0):

You can use prevState to see what is gonna be set in visible state

```
 onMouseLeave={()=>{
  setVisible((prevState) => {
       
        console.log('visibility is : ',prevState);
      })
 }}
```

so here prevState is exactly what is newest state in visible before rerendering